# send file to google speech API from C#

Tags: c#, http-post, speech-recognition

I'm trying to send a file to google speech API to get an interpretation. I already recorded the file and encoded it to flac.

Now I try to send it via POST, and receive the result. This is What I got so far:

```
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=44100");
        try
        {
            client.UploadFile("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?client=Mozilla/5.0&lang=es-ES&maxresults=10", "encodedTest.flac");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        client.OpenWriteCompleted += new System.Net.OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenWriteCompleted);
}
```

And then I plan to get the interfpretation like this:

```
void client_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, System.Net.OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Result);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
```

I always get an exception saying ERROR (400) Bad Request.

Does someone knows whats is wrong?
How can I get more details in the 400 Error (if I try to access from the browser I get 400 Bad Request your Content Type should be audio/xxx rate:xxx. I'd like to get some extra help from the code too)
Am I supposed to get correctly the response from google when the OpenWriteComplete is called?

Comment: please someone rate this comment down. Thats not true. I already tried with other interfaces (like cURL) and you can use different sample rate as long as you explicit that in the header

Comment: Ok, I can delete it, up to you. There is just little sense to send several times more data if result would be the same. So if you send 8khz audio you save quite a lot of bandwidth.